# Export cdf does not work in MathKernel command line

Tags: front-end, export, kernel, cdf-format, command-line

I am using Mathematica through command line `MathKernel`. I am not trying to draw any graphics in the console. But I should be able to export things a CDF. Why can't I export a CDF through command line ? Why do we need a graphical font end to export a CDF ? Is there any way around ? Interestingly `Show` did not throw error. However silently suppressed the circle.

```
In[1]:= TabView[{Show[Graphics[Circle[]]]}]                                                                        

Out[1]= TabView[{-Graphics-}]

In[2]:= Export["/tmp/file.cdf", TabView[{Show[Graphics[Circle[]]]}]]                                               

FrontEndObject::notavail: A front end is not available; certain operations require a front end.

Export::errelem: The Export element NotebookObject
     contains a malformed data structure and could not be exported to CDF format.

Out[2]= $Failed
```

I am actually trying to do the same through `WSTP` and getting the same result. So I was curious to check whether same happens with `MathKernel` or not.

Comment: Have you tried using `UsingFrontEnd @ Export[..]`?

Comment: What's that ? Never seen any thing like this. Will tomorrow and let you know. But what does it mean ?

Comment: ?UsingFrontEnd

UsingFrontEnd[expr] evaluates expr, making use of a front end if necessary. >>

Comment: I think the issue is that you are typing CDF when you mean PDF (as you have in the title).  If you change `/tmp/file.cdf` to `/tmp/file.pdf` everything works fine (Mathematica 11.1, Windows 7).

Comment: Sorry that was a typo

Comment: Thanks `UsingFrontEnd` worked. But why would Export need a frontend ? Isn't this a design flaw ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to put it other than `certain operations require a front end`. That's the way it is, interactive functionality (typical use-case of CDF) is implemented through the front end in Mathematica. So are `Graphics`. I think the question contains valuable information and Carl's comment should be an answer, but the question itself is ill-posed. Why Wolfram designed things the way they are is more often than not off-topic.